# Kubelet + prometheus: how to query if a pod is crashing?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, azure-aks, kubelet

I want to set up alerts when any pod in my Kubernetes cluster is in a `CrashloopBackOff` state. I'm running Kubelet on Azure Kubernetes Services and have set up a Prometheus Operator which exposes `metrics/cadvisor`.

Other similar questions on this topic, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410229/how-does-prometheus-know-when-a-pod-crashed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985164/alerts-in-k8s-for-pod-failing) are not relevant to Kubelet setups. The recommended `kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason{}`/`kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending|Unknown|Failed"}` and similar queries are not available to me with Kubelet on AKS.

Kubelet has somewhat limited metrics, here is what I have tried:

1. Container state:

```
container_tasks_state{container='my_container', kubernetes_azure_com_cluster='my_cluster'}
```

This seems like it *should* be the right solution, but the state is always 0, whether `Running` or in `CrashloopBackOff`. This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1672).

2. Time from start:

```
time() - container_start_time_seconds{kubernetes_azure_com_cluster='my_cluster', container='my_container'}
```

We can here notify when the time the container is live is low. Any pod with a repeat alert is crashing. Inelegant as healthy containers will also notify until they've lived long enough, also my alert channel becomes very noisy.

3. Detect exited containers:

```
kubelet_running_containers{kubernetes_azure_com_cluster='my_cluster', container_state='exited'}
```

Can detect a crashing container, but containers may also exit gracefully, so a notification on container exits is not very useful. We essentially get a 'container exited' alert and then need to manually check whether it was a crash or graceful exit.

4. Number of running pods:

```
kubelet_running_pods{kubernetes_azure_com_cluster='my_cluster'}
```

Does not change on a container crash.

5. Scrape error:

```
container_scrape_error{kubernetes_azure_com_cluster='my_cluster'}
```

Again, does not change on a container crash.

Which query will allow me to discover if a pod has entered the `CrashloopBackOff` state?